# Copy is not happening

Tags: python

Guyz - I am having this problem where shutil.copy tree thinks a directory exists even though it doesnt..both the source and directory are local...first time i ran it ran without errors but the content is actually not copied,second time it ran it thinks the directory already exists,details below..please provide your inputs,if there are any other ways to copy other than shutil..please suggest

Firs time ran,without any errors but it was not actually copied

```
  <username:/local/mnt/workspace/username/Scripts>python test.py
    //local/mnt/workspace/loc/04.01.01.00.303_HY11/out
    //local/mnt/workspace/test/out
    copying
```

Rerun second time,it thinks it thinks directory exists

```
    <username:/local/mnt/workspace/username/Scripts>python test.py
    //local/mnt/workspace/loc/04.01.01.00.303_HY11/out
    //local/mnt/workspace/test/out
    copying
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "test.py", line 21, in <module>
        main()
      File "test.py", line 18, in main
        copytree(src,dst)
      File "test.py", line 11, in copytree
        shutil.copytree(s, d)
      File "/pkg/qct/software/python/2.5.2/.amd64_linux26/lib/python2.5/shutil.py", line 110, in copytree
        os.makedirs(dst)
      File "/pkg/qct/software/python/2.5.2/.amd64_linux26/lib/python2.5/os.py", line 171, in makedirs
        mkdir(name, mode)
    OSError: [Errno 17] File exists: '//local/mnt/workspace/test/out'
    <username:/local/mnt/workspace/username/Scripts>
```

Python code

```
import os,shutil

def copytree(src, dst, symlinks=False, ignore=None):
    for item in os.listdir(src):
        s = os.path.join(src, item)
        print s
        d = os.path.join(dst, item)
        print d
        if os.path.isdir(s):
            print "copying"
            shutil.copytree(s, d, symlinks, ignore)
        else:
            shutil.copy2(s, d)
def main ():
    src="//local/mnt/workspace/loc/04.01.01.00.303_HY11"
    dst="//local/mnt/workspace/test"
    copytree(src,dst)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Have you actually _checked_ that the destination directory doesn't exist after the first time? Also, are there any files in the `out` subdirectory?

Comment: Can you show `tree` output before and after execution?

Comment: @Joachim - yes. out directory doesnt exist after first time...yes there are files in out subdirectory..is there any other way to copy other than shutil..it seems so unreliable

Comment: @ATOzTOA - tree output meaning?

Comment: `cd` to "//local/mnt/workspace/loc/04.01.01.00.303_HY11" and execute command `tree`. Copy paste the output.

Comment: This is working fine in Windows, first time it copies everything, second time, it do show error.

Comment: BTW, why are you writing your own copytree function, why don't you directly call shutil.copytree with `src` and `dst`?

Comment: @ATOzTOA - it gives the same output

Comment: Can you paste the output of `tree //local/mnt/workspace/test` and `tree //local/mnt/workspace/loc/04.01.01.00.303_HY11`? Also, does the folder `test` exist before copying?

Comment: source tree is really gigantic...hard to paste the tree... test exists,out doesnt exist on destination

Comment: @ATOzTOA - source tree is http://pastie.org/5629990..destination is empty

Comment: I have put in an answer, try it after clearing the destination and copy paste the `tree` output of destination.

Comment: What is the purpose of this program?

Comment: `shutil.copytree()` has no `ignore` parameter on Python 2.5 therefore your Python code doesn't correspond to the traceback. Post actual code. A single call  `shutil.copytree(src, dst)` should be enough in your case.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - am using python 2.6.5..actual code is exactly same as above..nothing different..its just that the source code is different..let me know what inof you need

Comment: why does your traceback show Python 2.5.2 files?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - that is resolved now..with ATOzTOA below not errors but copy is still not successful..am trying to copy from a linux box to a PC on the network...the code runs fine but in the end nothing is seen on the PC

Comment: try to use local posix paths: `shutil.copytree('/path/to/source', '/path/to/dest')`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - what would be the posix path for \\fos\IT\LA_CI_builds

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - also how will this resolve the problem of a linux box accessing a shared windows client location

Comment: to get local posix path, you [mount your network location as such via ssh, ftp, webdav or samba](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/22518/how-to-mount-a-remote-folder-in-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this version, the destination directory will be automatically cleared...

```
import os,shutil,errno

def copytree(src, dst, symlinks=False, ignore=None):
    if os.path.exists(dst):
        shutil.rmtree(dst)

    os.mkdir(dst)

    for item in os.listdir(src):
        s = os.path.join(src, item)
        d = os.path.join(dst, item)
        print s + " >> " + d

        if ".git" in s:
            return

        if os.path.isdir(s):
            print "Copying directory..."

            try:
                copytree(s, d, symlinks, ignore)

            except OSError as e: 
                # File already exist
                if e.errno == errno.EEXIST:
                    print "Path exists : " + d
        else:
            shutil.copy2(s, d)

def main ():
    src="//local/mnt/workspace/loc/04.01.01.00.303_HY11"
    dst="//local/mnt/workspace/test"
    copytree(src,dst)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: is it possible to add in the logic to delete existing diectory if it exists?

Comment: your update code started running but hit the error copyTraceback (most recent call last):
 
    copytree(s, d, symlinks, ignore)
  File "test.py", line 25, in copytree
    shutil.copy2(s, d)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/shutil.py", line 99, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/shutil.py", line 52, in copyfile
    fsrc = open(src, 'rb')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '//local/mnt/workspace/test/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB.04.01.01.00.343/docs/source.android.com/.git/svn'

Comment: i dont know why it is looking for this file..it doesnt exist in the source location

Comment: can we add a flag on not to copy .git directories for now if this cant be resolveD?

Comment: so far its running fine..source location has gigantic code..it will take time to finish...one question,copy is running but why am not seeing the code copied so far in destination directory

Comment: @user1927396 You don't see the files because you are copying to a removable media. Linux won't write the files to disk until you unmount the device.

Comment: even after the script is completed without erros..i dont see it being copied..am trying to copy from a linux location to a windows location ..windows location is empty

Comment: destination is something like dst="\\\aswbu\\location

Comment: Try unmounting the windows drive.

Comment: mounting and unmounting ..its just a windows location..am not doing any mounting or unmounting....anycommands you have to do this?

Comment: Try `tree` on destination and copy paste the result. Also, run `mount` and copy paste the result.

Comment: Which linux are you using? Show the output of `mount`.

Comment: Please run this command : `ls -l /aswbu/location` . If this won't work, then tell me how do you access windows files using command line.

Comment: i think we should mount the windows location to linux box and then copy..do you know how to do that?

Comment: How are you accessing the windows folders now?

Comment: I cant access through linux box..am just opening the windows folders in windows explorer...

Comment: Are you trying to copy to a different PC?

Comment: Wow... That will need some real work... And it is not related to programming, so we better not discuss it here... Try googling "access Windows from Linux through network"...

Comment: In short, first share the Windows folder on the network. Then use this tutorial : http://linhost.info/2012/05/mount-a-network-share-in-linux-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

May I ask why don't you use `shutil.copytree()` instead? If you do want to have a wrapper around `shutil.copytree()` (for considering existing directory, for example) name your function different such as `copytree_wrapper()` (Because you are mixing your `copytree` with `shutil.copytree`, and recursion is not involving your `copytree`) The following works for me:

```
import os,shutil

def copytree_wrapper(src, dst, symlinks=False, ignore=None): ### Name it different, no confusion!
    for item in os.listdir(src):
        s = os.path.join(src, item)
        print (s)
        d = os.path.join(dst, item)
        print (d)
        if os.path.isdir(s):
            print ("copying")
            if not os.path.exists(d): ### Create directory if does not already exist 
                print ("directory '%s' created" % d)
                os.makedirs(d)
            copytree_wrapper(s, d, symlinks, ignore) ### shutil.copytree(s, d, symlinks, ignore)
        else:
            shutil.copy2(s, d)
def main ():
    src="/tmp/a"
    dst="/tmp/b"
    copytree_wrapper(src,dst)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: @mg007 - i am going to try both yours and atoz's..is it possible to add the logic where to delete the existing destination directory if it exists

Comment: @ATOzTOA, The name was creating confusion to OP (it seems, because the snippet seemed like trying for recursion)

Comment: @mg007 - your code started copying but hit an error,how do we take care of these..is there a way to force copy IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '\\\\Test\\destloca\\CI/docs/source.android.com/.git/objects/pack/pack-cd66a03305bc9d6b4bb4cc53951148ee21c32831.idx'